# Time complexity of O(log n) in double nested loop function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I don't know how to calculate time complexity of this algorithm, I know nested loops is O(n^2) but i don't know what to do with .insert(), I came to wrong conclusion about it being O(n^2 + n log n) but I know I can't sum in big O, any help would be appreciated.

```
for i in range(arr_len):
     for j in range(arr_len):
         if (i == arr[j]):
             max_bin_heap.insert(//whatever) //O(log n)
```

Comment: If you're repeating something `O(n)` times and each time you do it it takes `O(n)` time, the entire thing takes `O(n * n)` time. If you're repeating something `O(n*n)` times and that something takes `O(log n))` time, how long does it take?

Comment: o(n * n * log n), thanks

Comment: How do you know `O(n^2 + n log(n))` is wrong? It seems the correct solution to me. You can sum in big O notation as long as the factors are terms defined in `n`. I do believe though that since `O(n^2 + nlog(n))` is considered equal to `O(n^2)` because `O(n^2)` is the faster growing term, so `O(n^2)` is probably the correct answer.

Comment: @qwerty12456 note that `O(n * n * log n)` is probably false.

Comment: You can most definitely sum in big-O. It just so happens that `O(a + b)` is equal to the "more complex" of the two. For instance, `O(N^2 + NlogN)` is simply `O(N^2)`. The idea is that big-O describes an upper bound of a function, and `NlogN` can be upper-bounded by `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, most people would say that this is `O(n*n*logn)` because of two nested loops and `O(logn)` operation `max_bin_heap.insert call` within the inner `for` loop. However, it is not! Pay attention to `if (i == arr[j])` condition. For each `j` from the inner `for` loop, at most one value of `i` will be equal to `arr[j]`, so two `for` loops will not induce `n^2` invocations of `max_bin_heap.insert call`, but only `n` of them. Since there are `n^2` comparisons and at most `n*logn` heap operations, the total complexity is `O(n*logn + n*n) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: You still do n^2 comparisons, so it's at least `O(n^2)` right?

Comment: @Glubus Correct!

Comment: I think that the statement "only one value of i will be equal to arr[j]"  could be completed with "at most".